# How can I filter on related taxonomy terms?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a list of Categories in my taxonomy, with each Category having a list of 'Related Categories' attached to them as a term reference field, ie :

```
Category - "Brushes" -> Related Categories -"Ink, Paints, Paper"
```

(Where each of the 'Related Categories' are a valid 'Category')

How can I adjust a view for a list of related products where it takes the current product's Category, and returns other products that match any of the 'Related Categories'?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way, and there's a better way? I was trying to reduce the amount of work, by, instead of attaching 'Related Categories' to each product (which would involve a lengthy data entry), tying the relation to the already set categories.

Mind you, each product can have multiple Categories assigned, which could complicate the situation.

Comment: How have you implemented the related categories?  Is it just a text list?

Comment: Yeah, are the related categories term references?  That would be best...

Comment: The related categories field is a term reference field on the category taxonomy field. (with unlimited number of values linked back to the Categories vocabulary)